# laravel blade PHP code not evaluated in PHP 5.6

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-5

After upgrading to a new version of PHP (from 5.4.7 to 5.6.3) my Laravel Blade templates do not evaluate PHP code anymore.

For example I may have a file test.blade.php:

```
<? if(TRUE) echo "I am "?> {{1==1}}
```

Instead of outputting "I am true" the blade part is evaluated but the PHP code is not resulting in the following rendered output:

```
<? if(TRUE) echo "I am "?> true
```

I know there are specific Blade tags for control statements but this is merely an example. Does anyone know what's going on here? I don't really feel like rewriting all blade views to be PHP-less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorttags are disabled by default in later PHP versions. Can't believe I missed that!

Comment: Good catch! There is always some details we usually forget